# Analysis of interactions in quantile regression models

Tags: regression, r, interaction, feature-selection, quantile-regression

I possess a large dataset with `n ~10,000`. My goal is to develop a quantile regression model using `rq()` from the `quantreg` R package. I have selected `tau` values ranging from 0.1 to 0.9 in increments of 0.1.

I am considering the analysis of interactions: my model includes both categorical and continuous independent variables - a total of 10 variables.

**Questions:**

1. Should I perform the analysis of potential interactions for each pair of dependent variables (45 in total) or only for those interactions that are theoretically rational?
2. Should I analyze only pairs of variables [e.g., `qr(y ~ a + b + a*b, data = data, tau=0.5)`?] or interactions across the entire model?
3. Should the analysis be conducted for all `tau` values of interest?
4. How can I verify whether potential interactions improve the model's performance? Would `AIC.rq()` be appropriate?

I am aware that conducting an analysis of numerous interactions could result in many false positive associations. I have previously removed variables that exhibited multicollinearity.

Comment: What do you want to learn from your quantile regressions?

Comment: Y: number of likes on social media
one categorical variable: non-anon account (verified), other categorical variable - dummy variables of type of accounts (music genres, removed one to omit dummy variable trap). Continuous variables: number of followers, length of message, sentiment of message. 
I really do not know about possible interaction. Could soul musicians type longer posts which may increase number of likes? Or non-anon account post more positive (positive sentiment) posts; thus, obtain more likes? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you mainly care about prediction, consider including all interactions and using regularized estimation (lasso, ridge, elastic net, SCAD, ...) or best subset selection. There are R packages such as [`rqPen`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rqPen/index.html) and [`cqrReg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cqrReg/index.html) that can do regularized estimation (even the `quantreg` package has lasso: [`rq.fit.lasso`](https://web.mit.edu/%7Er/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/quantreg/html/rq.fit.lasso.html)); not sure about subset selection, though. You could also try a quantile neural network from [`qrnn`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qrnn/index.html), as per Dave's reference. If you really wish to stick to `rq` from `quantreg`, that leaves only best subset selection (from the suggestions above).

If you want inference about some parameters, you probably have a sufficient sample size for splitting into training and test samples, training and selecting a model on the training sample and doing inference on the test sample.

More specifically to your questions:

1. If some interactions make zero sense, I would exclude them from the model.
2. This is about getting the complexity of the model just right. Including all pairwise interactions yields 55 variables together with main effects, and that is probably fine with the sample size of yours. Including one more level of interactions is probably a bit too much.
3. For the more extreme quantiles (`tau=0.1` or `tau=0.9`) the estimation precision will be lower, so simpler models could be better. At least I would not try a more flexible model for `tau=0.1` or `tau=0.9` than for `tau=0.5`.
4. I am not exactly sure how `AIC.rq` works and what model the AIC value corresponds to, so I am not sure whether you should use it. Alternatively, you may try cross validation where you would evaluate your model on the left-out folds. This might be computationally expensive, though.

Comment: If you're going to throw the kitchen sink at the problem, then why not go with a neural network in a package like `qrnn`?

Comment: @Dave, because the OP writes *My goal is to develop a quantile regression model using `rq()` from the `quantreg` R package.* And now I realize my answer violates that requirement, thus updated. More seriously, `qrnn` could work, too. Whether the reduced interpretability and added complexity (and computational time) is worth it is for the OP to decide.